# consulta por intervalos de tiempo en mysql

Tags: mysql

El problema es el siguiente,tengo una tabla: `filter-log` que guarda datos extraidos de un archivo log de actividades con los siguientes campos: `id_log, ip, fecha, hora, consulta, code`. Les muestro algunos registros:

```
1, 190.168.65.45, 2017-10-13, 12:07:30,categories.php?cat=carteras,A  
2, 190.168.65.45, 2017-10-13, 12:22:33,categories.php?cat=bolso,B  
3, 190.168.65.222, 2017-10-13, 15:30:22,categories.php?cat=zapatos,C  
4, 190.168.65.240, 2017-10-14, 12:21:10,categories.php?cat=carteras,A  
5, 190.168.65.240, 2017-10-14, 12:35:09, categories.php?cat=correas,D  
6, 190.168.65.45, 2017-10-15, 15:20:51, categories.php?cat=correas,D  
7, 190.168.65.45, 2017-10-15, 15:25:01, categories.php?cat=carteras,A  
8, 190.168.249.38, 2017-10-16, 16:45:13, categories.php?cat=zapatos,C  
9, 190.168.249.38, 2017-10-16, 16:53:22, categories.php?cat=carteras,A  
10, 190.168.249.38, 2017-10-16, 18:25:42, categories.php?cat=zapatos,C
```

entonces, **¿qué necesito?**

Generar una consulta que devuelva las transacciones
realizadas de la misma ip por intervalo de tiempo (30min) y la misma
fecha.

**Ejemplo:**

Los que tienen el `id` 1 y 2 se mostrarían juntos en un
grupo o record.

El que tiene el id 3 se mostraría solo, y así
sucesivamente.

Fíjense que 8 y 9 van juntos pero 10 no porque no está en
el intérvalo de tiempo de 30 min, formaría parte de otro grupo.

---

Ya he intentado con funciones `mysql` que he encontrado googleando como `INTERVAL`, `GROUP BY`, pero no doy con la solución, alguna orientación?

Comment: Por favor lee lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Aunque has explicado tu problema, yo la verdad solo entendí esta parte de tu problema `necesito entonces realizar una consulta que me devuelva las transacciones por intervalo de tiempo (30min) y de una misma ip y la misma fecha...` = ¿has probado con una función que se llame cada 30 minutos?, usando javascript, usa setTimeout cuya función llamaría a tu función PHP que hace la consulta...

Comment: Por ahora haría falta que trates de explicar en un sólo párrafo lo que quieres hacer, sin tantos detalles, muchos de ellos oscuros. Quizá no sea tan difícil y te has perdido en tantas explicaciones porque te perdiste un poco con todo el sistema. Escribe un párrafo o dos donde digas qué quieres hacer y según tú, con cuáles tablas lo harías.

Comment: Dudo mucho que puedas procesar lo que necesitas en una única query. Si lo tienes que hacer directamente a nivel de base de datos vas a necesitar un procedimiento almacenado. Podrías hacerlo en un intervalo de tiempo determinado, pero como lo que tienes que procesar va en relación al resto de valores de las tuplas, me parece que eso es miga de cursor.

Comment: Grx frikinside, ahorita estoy probando y combinando con esta consulta que me facilitó un amigo <br/>                                                                          SELECT ip,fecha,count(*) as cantidad
,CONCAT(substring(hora,1,4),'0') as hora_desde
,substring(ADDTIME(CONCAT(substring(hora,1,4),'0'), '00:09'),1,5) as hora_fin
FROM `registro_log` 
group by ip,fecha,substring(hora,1,4) 
order by ip,fecha,substring(hora,1,4)  <br/> ,                                                  pero aún no me retorna el resultado esperado